# Browse a remote Apache server webpage through a VPN

Tags: apache-2.2, openvpn, centos6

I'm using openVPN to connect to a remote server running Centos 6.x where I have already installed Apache, PHP and Mysql. Now I would like to test if the LAMP stack is properly configured and if the web page load. Is it possible to browse the webpage from my client web browser through the VPN?

this is the ovpn file configuration:

```
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Server Authentication"
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
mute 20
keepalive 10 60
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
float
reneg-sec 3660
nobind
mute-replay-warnings
auth-user-pass
;remember_connection 0
;auto_reconnect 1
```

this is the remote server netstat:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0     40 srv-zsd.com.pov:ssh 192.168.113.2:62149  

   ESTABLISHED
```

and after `netstat -tuplen`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          11832256   -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          11832722   -                   
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          11922117   -                   
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          11832258   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      0          11832723   -
```

I connect to the vpn like this:  `ssh admin.xyz@192.168.10.213`

And in the browser I get `192.168.10.213 refused to connect.`

Comment: Of course it's possible. What do you actually need help with?

Comment: @MichaelHampton thx for the help, I added some more info

Comment: I found a solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/569226/serving-a-web-page-through-vpn-and-ssh-locally-on-a-remote-computer) with port forwarding.